# Why can't we combine arguments in subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess

When using `subprocess.Popen`, we have to write

```
with subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    print(proc.stdout.read())
```

instead of

```
with subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l -a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    print(proc.stdout.read())
```

Why? What `ls` will get in the second case? Thank you.

Comment: You can't run `ls '-l -a'` in a shell either. Try it.

Answer (score 3):

When your operating system starts an executable, it does this via a call something very much like this:

```
execv('/usr/bin/ls', 'ls', '-l', '-a', NULL)
```

Note that the arguments are already split out into individual words before `ls` is started; if you're running your program with a shell, then the shell is responsible for doing that splitting; if you're running it via a programming language that lets you control the `execv` call's arguments directly, then you're deciding how to split the array up yourself.

When `ls` runs, it's passed those arguments in an array, `argv`. Witness the usual way a `main` function is declared in C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ...
}
```

It's getting an *array* of arguments, in a variable conventionally named `argv`, already broken up into individual words.

The parser for `ls`, then, can expect that when it's run it will be handed an array that looks like this:

```
argc = 3                   # three arguments, including our own name
argv = ['ls', '-l', '-a']  # first argument is our name, others follow
```

...so the command-line parser built into `ls` doesn't need to break up spaces inside of its arguments -- spaces have already been removed, and syntactic quotes honored and stripped, before the `ls` command is ever started.

Now, when you run `['ls', '-l -a']`, you're explicitly specifying an argc of 2, not 3, and a single argument that includes a single string `-l -a`. To get that behavior from a shell, you'd need to use quoting or escaping:

```
ls "-l -a"
ls '-l -a'
ls -l\ -a
```

...and you'll find that `ls` fails the exact same way as what you get here when invoked from a shell with any of those usages.

Comment: Note: on Windows, it is a [different story](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I was a happier person (however naively so) before I followed that link. Compiler-specific argv assembly? Ewwww!

Answer (score 1):

In the second case `-l -a` as a single string will be the first argument to `ls`, which it won't know what to do with, or at least won't do what you want.  In the first case `-l` is the first argument and `-a` is the second argument.

If you want to build a string that has the complete command you can use the `shell=True` flag to Popen, but then your command would be `"ls -l -a"` not `['ls', '-l -a']`

With `Popen` each argument in the list is an argument passed to the command being executed, it's not a string passed to the shell to be interpreted, unless you ask for it to be passed to the shell to be interpreted.

Comment: ...and, to be clear, when using `shell=True`, the string `"ls -l -a"` would be changed into an argv array of `['ls', '-l', '-a']` by that shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use string representation of command to execute, [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module may be useful.

> shlex.split(s[, comments[, posix]])
>
> Split the string s using shell-like syntax. If comments is False (the default), the parsing of comments in the given string will be
>   disabled (setting the commenters attribute of the shlex instance to
>   the empty string). This function operates in POSIX mode by default,
>   but uses non-POSIX mode if the posix argument is false.

```
assert shlex.split("ls -a -l") == ['ls', '-a', '-l']
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("ls -a -l"))
```

It also covers more complex cases like escaping chars or quotes usage:

```
assert shlex.split("cat 'file with space.txt'") == ['cat', 'file with space.txt']
assert shlex.split(r"cat file\ with\ space.txt") == ['cat', 'file with space.txt']
```